# ipad detecting date as a telephone number and inserting a tel link

Tags: ios, ipad, css, responsive-design, tel

I have the following for a responsive project:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>Besteldatum</td>
                <td itemprop="description">
                    24-2-2014
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Losse editie</td>
                <td itemprop="description">
                    2014-02
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Strangely enough the ipad places a link in the first  as if it were a telephone, check the image:

[image]

If I inspect in the ipad I see that the HTML is converted into the following:

```
<table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>Besteldatum</td>
                <td itemprop="description">
                    <a href="tel:24-2-2014">24-2-2014</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Losse editie</td>
                <td itemprop="description">
                    2014-02
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

I think the ipad is detecting this date as a telephone number and placing this link automatically. I have other links with the tel link so I would like a solution that does not cancel the other tel links.

Never seen this, can anybody help?

Comment: I tried by placing the numbers inside a <time> tag, but no success.

Comment: Off-topic: What is the font on the screenshot?

Comment: @Mark This is Titillium Web, check it Google fonts. Quite popular font I think.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't seen it before. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is default behaviour in iOS. It means that users can simply click a phone number on a web page to make a phone call. Unfortunately it does pick up some non-phone numbers sometimes depending on the formatting.

You have a few options. Here are a couple. Either disable iOS phone number detection by adding this meta tag:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

This maybe a bad idea because it will remove the phone number detection for the entire page making real phone numbers non-clickable.

or override the styles that are being applied with something like...

```
a[href^=tel] {
    color: #your_color;
    text-decoration: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

If you have some genuine phone numbers on the page, you may wish to add a class to the non-phone parent in order to differentiate:

```
    .date a[href^=tel] {
        color: #your_color;
        text-decoration: none;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

Comment: I'm using the meta data. Do you know if I use after a link with tel: it will work in ipad even if I have this meta data applied to the page?

Comment: I believe so. You may have to test.